# MLEs of $(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for restricted parameter space

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, estimation, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be a random sample of size $n$ from $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Find the MLEs of $\mu,\sigma$ if $\mu \in [-1,1]$ and $1 \le \sigma^2 \le 5$. Now, we know that had the restrictions been not imposed on $\mu , \sigma^2$; the MLEs are easy to find. They are precisely given by $\bar{X} , \frac{1}{n} \sum (X_i - \bar{X})^2$ respectively. But how to find the MLEs in this case?

Comment: Either the maximum over the whole range is within these bounds, or you need to search along the boundary of the region, which can probably be done analytically to find the maximum along the four lines containing the boundary segments and on the four vertices.

Comment: Yeah , but can you give a precise argument why the maximum holds only on the boundaries?

Comment: I'm not sure what "the maximum holds only on the boundaries" means, could you clarify?

Comment: @jwimberley is correct.You're trying to maximize the likelihood or log-likelihood over a domain, and you know from your calculus classes that extrema occur where the gradient is zero _within the domain_ or at the boundaries of the domain. Always check the boundaries.

Comment: @jwimberley I mean that why only to check the four boundary points $\{ -1,1\} \times \{ 1,5 \}$?

Comment: @MathsFreak It's not true that you only need to check the four boundary points, so there's no precise argument for that, look over rural reader's comment and mine again

Comment: Think about an easier problem. How would you find the maximum of $f(x) := (1+x)^2$ for $1 \geq x \geq 0$?